# add a row to a datatable from a row in a different datatable

Tags: c#

i am currently doing this:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
    {
        dt_final.Rows.Add(dt.Rows[i]);
    }
```

but i am getting an error that this row belongs to another table. how do i import this row to dt_final table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can only add rows that where created from the DataTable (ie throug NewRow). But you can import a row from a different table

```
 dt_final.ImportRow(dt.Rows[i]);
```

Comment: I think you meant `dt_final.ImportRow(dt.Rows[i]);` ;)